cmake building a project with conan files generates an error
I'm trying to run a project for an example of the Oat++ framework by loading libraries using conan.
My algorithm of actions:

In the project directory, I run the command

conan install  . --output-folder=build --build=missing 

(after this command, the conan_toolchain.cmake file is created in the ./build)

In the ./build directory, I run the command

cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build/conan_toolchain.cmake

I am a beginner in this topic, I will be glad of any help!
conanfile.txt:
[requires]
oatpp/1.3.0
oatpp-swagger/1.3.0
oatpp-websocket/1.3.0
oatpp-openssl/1.3.0

[generators]
CMakeToolchain
CMakeDeps

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(project_name my-project)

project(${project_name})

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_toolchain.cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(${project_name}-lib
    src/AppComponent.hpp
    src/controller/MyController.cpp
    src/controller/MyController.hpp
    src/dto/DTOs.hpp
)

## link libs
find_package(oatpp REQUIRED)
find_package(oatpp-swagger REQUIRED)
find_package(oatpp-websocket REQUIRED)
find_package(oatpp-openssl REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_deps/include
)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-lib
    oatpp::oatpp
    oatpp::oatpp-swagger
    oatpp::oatpp-websocket
    oatpp::oatpp-openssl
)

target_include_directories(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC src)

## add executables
add_executable(${project_name}-exe
    src/App.cpp
    test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp
)
target_link_libraries(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)

add_executable(${project_name}-test
    test/tests.cpp
    test/app/TestComponent.hpp
    test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp
    test/MyControllerTest.cpp
    test/MyControllerTest.hpp
)

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-test ${project_name}-lib)

set_target_properties(${project_name}-lib ${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-test PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)

enable_testing()
add_test(project-tests ${project_name}-test)


The structure of the OATTP_STARTER project:
./build
./src
./test
CMakeLists.txt
conanfile.txt

In directories ./src and ./test have other directories and project files.
At the cmake build stage with the command
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build/conan_toolchain.cmake 

I get an error:

CMake Warning:
  Ignoring extra path from command line:

   ".cmake"


-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:152 (message):
  Could not find toolchain file: build/conan_toolchain
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

================================================================
The above problem has been solved (namely, the cmake build error has disappeared). However, another problem has appeared
C:\Users\h4thq\prjcts\oat2\oatpp-starter\build>cmake --build . --config Release
MSBuild version 17.10.4+10fbfbf2e for .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/h4thq/prjcts/oat2/oatpp-starter/CMakeLists.txt
  MyController.cpp
C:\Users\h4thq\prjcts\oat2\oatpp-starter\src\dto\DTOs.hpp (4.10): error C1083: Unable to open file enable: oa
http/macro/codegen.hpp: No such file or directory, [C:\Users\h4thq\prjcts\oat2\oatpp-starter\build\my-project-lib.vc
xprog]

This time I tried to find information about this case, but I couldn't. As far as I understand, conan files seem to be unavailable.
Do you have any thoughts on this?

The toolchains cannot be include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_toolchain.cmake), this is incorrect, and won't work. It has to be passed in command line argument.

In command line you might also quote -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="build/conan_toolchain.cmake", as it seems this is a terminal command line parsing issue

you're in the build directory so -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=build/conan_toolchain.cmake means it'll look for build/build/conan_toolchain.cmake, try -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake

Why don't you start from the conan documentation? Here https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial.html you can find everything on how to use it with easy step-by-step instructions.

@drodri, thanks for the advice with quotes.It helped.

@ElvisDukaj, thank you for the helpful link. My mistake is that I didn't get acquainted in advance.

In my case, @drodri's advice helped:In command line you might also quote -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="build/conan_toolchain.cmake", as it seems this is a terminal command line parsing issue

There are several errors in your CMake file. Probably you will need to spend a bit more time to understand how conan and cmakes works. A good starting point would be the conan-io tutorial page.
Some of the issues I found:

No need for including conan_toolchain.cmake:
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_toolchain.cmake)

It's not needed anymore. The integration between conan and CMake is transparent and is happening passing the toolchain file in the command line or via the cmake profiles.

No need for
target_include_directories(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_deps/include
)

When using target_link_libraries include directories, libraries, and every other public property will be inherited.

No need to specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

This is because you could potentially link to libraries that were built with some other C++ standard causing issues (best case at compile time).
The C++ version is given by the conan profile. You can also pass it on the command line with --settings compiler.cppstd=17,

Use always config target to avoid. Consider write:
## link libs

find_package(oatpp CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(oatpp-swagger CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(oatpp-websocket CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(oatpp-openssl CONFIG REQUIRED)

This will ensure that only the target generated by conan will be considered.

Consider using CMake profiles instead. When you run conan install . --build=missing read carefully the output. In my system looks like the following:
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain: Preset 'conan-release' added to CMakePresets.json.
    (cmake>=3.23) cmake --preset conan-release
    (cmake<3.23) cmake <path> -G Ninja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake  -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

Running the command it's really straightforward:
cmake --preset conan-release
Preset CMake variables:

CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release"
CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW"
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH="generators\conan_toolchain.cmake"

-- Using Conan toolchain:    C:/xrsw/repos/toDelete/build/Release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake
-- Conan toolchain: C++ Standard 14 with extensions OFF
-- Conan: Component target declared 'oatpp::oatpp'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'oatpp-test::oatpp-test'
-- Conan: Target declared 'oatpp::oatpp-test'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'oatpp::oatpp-swagger'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'oatpp::oatpp-websocket'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'oatpp::oatpp-openssl'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'OpenSSL::Crypto'
-- Conan: Component target declared 'OpenSSL::SSL'
-- Conan: Target declared 'openssl::openssl'
-- Conan: Target declared 'ZLIB::ZLIB'
-- Conan: Including build module from 'C:/Users/EDUKAJ/.conan2/p/b/opens007823a800882/p/lib/cmake/conan-official-openssl-variables.cmake'
-- Configuring done (0.3s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/xrsw/repos/toDelete/build/Release

To build just call cmake: cmake --build --preset conan-release

Use the cmake_layout instead of passing the output folder like you did:
[layout]
cmake_layout


I would also suggest to use Ninja Multi-Config. This will avoid you to override debug/release builds and you can keep everything in the same folder.

Please always make explicit PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE when using target_* calls. For instance:
target_link_libraries(${project_name}-lib
PUBLIC
 oatpp::oatpp
 oatpp::oatpp-swagger
 oatpp::oatpp-websocket
 oatpp::oatpp-openssl
)




None of those suggestion targets a problem described in the question post. 1-4 are about lines of code which are not executed because of the error. Suggestion in 4 to always use CONFIG mode for find_package is quite controversial.

Suggestion 1. and 2. should address the problem. I replicated the situation removing the conan specific code from CMakeList.txt and verified it myself. Why do you think it's not solving the problem?

The error message is about project() call at line 5. The suggestions 1-4 are about following lines. (E.g. include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan_toolchain.cmake) is at line 7.)
